# Is there a simple way to create a Python App with Qt that is accessible through the web browser?

Tags: python, qt, browser

I'm an experienced python developer, although I have never developed web applications. I have a relatively simple application that access a database (SQLite), and has a neat GUI written in Qt5. I need to hand in this application to several colleagues, and I don't want to wrap it into an exe file with cx_freeze: I would rather like to make it available through a web browser via internet. I have researched the internet and I saw solutions like flask and web.py, but I haven't found a solution that does not involve writing HTML and javascript code. I'm not familiar with these things. Is is possible to simply make my Qt-based application accessible via web ? I would not mind if I have to rewrite the GUI with another library that makes this possible, but I would not like to have to learn HTML and such stuff. So I wonder whether there is a "black-box" like library that would allow me to deploy my app.

Thank you ! 
Rafael.

Comment: If you want to develop a website (webapp/buzzword), you have to develop a website. There's not really a way around it. Qt is a SDL/GL wrapper with pre-defined widgets. There's nothing in that spec that's "web". And there's no way to serve local application GUI's/framworks via the web. There are webGL.. But that on its own isn't directly translateable to Qt or again, any local framework. There's Qt-alike [frameworks for web](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) as well, but again, you're hoping for the stars but you'll be sorely dissapointed to learn that yes, you need to learn and code.

Comment: @Torxed , many thanks for your reply. As I said, I don't mind learning a new library, I think I was just a bit overwhelmed with the numerous frameworks available and thought that there was no solution that involved "widget-like" interface development for the Web. It all seems to converge to HTML and Javascript. Could you be more specific and maybe recommed me a combination of frameworks that allow me to develop my web app with in a relatively straightforward way ? The focus should be in the functionality of the application itself, not on the web development...

Comment: Learn at least HTML and CSS. then use Python/Flask. You can avoid JS if you make a server-side only app. But you might want to learn JS too in the long run. As a curiosity there is pyjamas but I never used it and last release looks old. If anybody had recent experience with it... But you are better going with fist option. If you want everything out of the way there is bottlepy, but no way to avoid HTML/CSS. Don't make it a drama. Basic HTML and CSS can do a good job. Without JS you can look a bit old fashioned, but there are also CSS frameworks like bootstrap that can help you.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider using remote desktop web client? then all you need is to setup a PC for your colleagues to remote.

Comment: @HenryYik I think that would be a rather clumsy way to access in the end. But it could work in the short term.

Comment: @progmatico Thanks for your reply. Yes, after reading the replies here it became clear that I do need to dive into web technologies (HTML, CSS, flask, bootstrap) in order to do development of web apps. I've found an amazing course in Udemy that will help me to kick-start this.